# Force parent window of iFrame into Compatability mode without access?

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer, cross-browser

Facebook is having allot of JavaScript issues at the moment in Internet Explorer (IE 9),  however by clicking the IE 8 Compatibility Mode button, or by switching to IE 8 Compatibility via the Developer tools you can get rid of all the JavaScript errors.

My apps are using the newer iFrame method, I have tried the following tags:

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=IE8" />

Neither seemed to switch the parent frame into the correct mode (document.documentMode != 8), is there a way to force IE 9 into Compatibility mode for the whole site (facebook.com) from within a iFrame either via JavaScript or some undocumented method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not unless you have control of the site.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [compatilbility-view](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1220-internet-explorer-compatilbility-view-all-websites.html)

In a web application where I had access to the server, I added a custom HTTPHeader entry for the target web site:

```
Custom Header name: X-UA-Compatible
Custom Header value:  IE=EmulateIE7
```

In order to force IE8 to behave like IE7, and it worked well.

Comment: Yeah, the simple answer is it can't be done, since all the X-UA-Compatible stuff in an iframe doesn't change the parent domain compatibility mode.

Comment: @DevelumPHP: right. I misread the question. In my case I could access the parent site. sorry.