# IE - Prevent compatibility mode in an Iframe

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

Is it possible to disable the IE compatibility mode from within an Iframe?

If I use the following meta in the `iframe` html, this not working:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11; IE=10; IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE" />
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Force parent window of iFrame into Compatability mode without access?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758316/force-parent-window-of-iframe-into-compatability-mode-without-access)

Comment: It's the same problem: "I want to *<do something>* to the document including me via an iframe" with the same answer: You cannot do that unless you own the document that contains the iframe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on if you have access to the x-ua-compatible meta of the host (parent).  When the host page is at IE9 mode or above, its state is imposed on the iframe.  Here's a good explanation, given by a moderator at MS-Connect.
https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/1047106/when-webpage-emulates-ie-5-embedded-iframe-shows-ie-8
Here's supplemental info about how Quirks mode forked two ways beginning with IE10.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh869300(v=vs.85).aspx
Here's a live demo which allows changing the IE modes on-the-fly.
It was [patched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29857001/changing-the-compatibility-mode-of-ie-programmatically-when-working-with-shdocvw) to also allow selecting the iframe url.
https://googledrive.com/host/0B8BLd2qPPV7XfnZQRk1JSkg5cFVMbGI1QkZVclVBbUtWZnV2bmczUHpSaVJmSXBOdUg2ek0/toggle-IE-compat-and-quirks-modes.html